# How can i remove Vat Number field in customer address form admin?

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent, ui

I want to remove Vat Number field in customer address form in admin.Anyone have any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `customer_form.xml` file to custom module

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml
```

With below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="address">
        <field name="vat_id" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

It would be remove VAT number from customer address in Admin.